# diccionario-dataframe & filtrado por fechas

Tags: python, datetime, diccionarios

estoy con un ejercicio con el cual me estoy atascando un poco, a ver si podéis echarme una mano.

El enunciado del ejercicio pide generar un diccionario a partir de un dataframe que contiene registros de concentración de distintas moléculas, registros tomados por diferentes estaciones meteorológicas, con diferentes fechas asignadas a cada registro.
Nos quedaremos con los datos anteriores a fecha "15-03-2020"

La estructura del archivo es del tipo

```
Station, Molecule, date1, date2, date3,
ES01     SO         0.4    0.3    0.5
ES01     NO         0.5    0.2    0.1
ES03     SO         0.1    0.4    0.5
```

el diccionario ha de ser del tipo

```
{
"Molecule_1": {"registration date": [31/01/18, 28/02/18,...], "monthly concentration (ug/m3)": [0, 0,...]},
"Molecule_2": {"registration date": [31/01/18, 28/02/18,...], "monthly concentration (ug/m3)": [0, 0,...]},
"Molecule_3": {"registration date": [31/01/18, 28/02/18,...], "monthly concentration (ug/m3)": [0, 0,...]},
"Molecule_4": {"registration date": [31/01/18, 28/02/18,...], "monthly concentration (ug/m3)": [0, 0,...]},
}
```

he intentado plantear el ejercicio generando un dataframe con columnas por cada una de las fechas, incluyendo dos columnas que contendrán las estaciones y moleculas. Llegados a este punto, genero una función avg para sacar la media de registros por molécula en cada fecha.

Dejo a continuación el código.

```
from datetime import datetime

def save_pickle (location: str,date: str):
      
    data = pd.read_csv(location)
    date_dt = datetime.strptime(date, '%d/%m/%Y')
    list_columns=data.columns.tolist()
    list_columns=list_columns[2:]


    def fecha_conversion(value):
        value = datetime.strptime (value, '%d/%m/%Y')
        return value
        
    def fecha_filter(value):
        if value < date_dt:
            return True  

    list_columns=list (map(fecha_conversion,list_columns))

    list_columns= list (filter(fecha_filter, list_columns))
    
    
    def fecha_conversion2(value):
        value = value.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
        return value
    
    list_columns= list (map(fecha_conversion2, list_columns))
 
    molecules = pd.DataFrame ()
           
    for i in list_columns:
        molecules.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
        data.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)       
        molecules[i]=data[i] 
        
    molecules_1=data[["Station","Molecule"]]
    result=pd.concat([molecules_1, molecules], axis=1)
    result = result.groupby("Molecule", as_index=False).mean()
    return result
```

Hasta este punto, obtengo un dataframe del tipo

```
Molecule    31/01/2018  28/02/2018  31/03/2018  30/04/2018  31/05/2018  30/06/2018  31/07/2018  31/08/2018  30/09/2018  31/10/2018
0   NO  0.336154    0.279231    0.206154    0.192308    0.239231    0.267692    0.266154    0.302308    0.343846    0.349231
1   NO2     2.972308    2.943846    2.130000    2.060000    2.353846    2.112308    2.419231    2.657692    2.941538    3.002308
2   O3  60.076923   67.538462   78.692308   84.153846   84.538462   77.769231   83.384615   82.538462   80.000000   68.692308
3   SO2     0.463077    0.537692    0.426154    0.471538    0.442308    0.472308    0.560000    0.650000    0.527692    0.499231
```

El problema lo tengo en pasar a una configuración tipo diccionario, he probado lo siguiente

```
result.set_index('Molecule').T.to_dict('list')
```

El problema es que con esta alternativa genero un diccionario con clave "Molecule", y valores la media de los registros, pero pierdo la opción de recoger los valores de las vechas para cada uno de los registros (ver configuración de diccionario pedida arriba).

Gracias por adelantado,

Un saludo.

Comment: Pista: `data.to_json()`

Comment: Buen día, creo que el link al CSV podría estar mal, descargué todos los archivos y ninguno tiene la estructura que mencionas

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta "HeytalePazguato". Realmente el csv de trabajo es una composición de datos hecha a partir de la información proporcionada en el enlace. He editado la respuesta para intentar ilustrar la información que contiene.

Comment: Tras progresar algo más con el código, he conseguido solventar algunos de los problemas inciales. Pendiente aún de conseguir una conversión a diccionario.